# Change value of cell in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to alter the value of a cell in a table through Javascript. Here is my code so far:

```
 var field = document.getElementById('cellID').focus();
```

This returns to me "undefined", which I have gathered means that it finds my field(otherwise it would return null). This "field" has a default text value in it that I want to change. I have tried this:

```
 field.innerHTML = "HelloStackOverflow";
```

But the default text does not change when I run my javascript, it simply stays the same.

Does anybody have a tip how to proceed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try removing `.focus()`.

Comment: Why do you add `.focus()` at the end?

Comment: You are trying to get the element before your page is loaded. User jQuery and wrap it on document ready function o do it with native js with window.onload function

Comment: @DiogoCapela How can you possibly know that this code is not already inside an onload event?

Comment: Do you have any specific cell where you want to change your value ?

Comment: `focus()` is not required. Try without that. It should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This returns to me "undefined", which I have gathered means that it
>   finds my field(otherwise it would return null)

[focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) doesn't return the element reference (in fact doesn't return anything, hence `undefined`), so remove the `focus()` at the end

```
var field = document.getElementById('cellID');
field.innerHTML = "HelloStackOverflow"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but you should remove `.focus()` from your variable declaration.  That would apply focus to an element, rather than return an assignment to a variable.

Here's a basic working example:

```js
var field = document.getElementById('cell2');  // assign the reference to the cell

function changeCell() {
  field.innerText = "HelloStackOverflow";  // change the cell's text
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td id="cell2">Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br />
<button onclick="changeCell();">Click to change cell 2 text</button>
```